# Пароли в EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Всем привет. Недавно начал разработку своего приложения. Начальный экран состоит из полей EditText для ввода e-maila и пароля пользователя. Справа в EditText стоит drawable/eye, как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на этот значок пароль показывался? [image]

Comment: По идее оно сразу должно работать. У вас не работает, получается? Как именно вы проверяете и где?

Comment: Проверял на своём устройстве Xiaomi Redmi Note 9S, при вводе пароля и нажатия на глаз ничего не меняется. Я думал, что нужен обработчик нажатия для глаза, вот так объявляю глаз                       `android:drawableRight="@drawable/eye"`

Comment: По идее функционал, нужный вам, надо не иконкой добавлять, которая, понятно, ничего делать не будет, а через указание типа вводимых данных, заменив, немного, вьюху, которая используется. Попробуйте пример кода отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41163578/3212712.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не надо пытаться изобретать велосипеды, "глазик" с показыванием пароля поддерживается через `TextInputLayout`, примерно так:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"> <!-- наличие глазика контролируется здесь -->
     <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
          android:id="@+id/passwordEdit"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:inputType="textPassword"
      />
 </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Подключается через: `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'`

[Документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout)